# Nuxt Deploy not working, only load main page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, web-deployment

when doing a "npm run build" my application has stopped working and only loads the main page. Does anyone know what is the reason for this? Thanks.

[github repository with files](https://github.com/jsanchez-98/nuxt-deploy-files)

With this package-lock.json, we can do "npm install" and "npm run build" and works fine, but when we do a "git pull" on server, we can't do build and that's what appears [image: image npm run build]

then we delete package-lock.json and do "npm install" and "npm run build". Now a new package-lock.json has been generated, we do another time "npm install" and "npm run build" and that's what appears [image: image npm run build] but the project is not loading content correctly, we only see the main page but also is not working correctly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow ! Can you give more debugging details please ? [ask]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have just updated the post.

Comment: Please, paste the images and actual text here rather than uploading it to wetransfer.

Comment: i push files into github repository

Comment: Oooh but wait, why are you posting your `package-lock.json` ? `package.json` is usually far more readable and enough to troubleshoot package related issues.

Comment: I'm posting that file because we noticed that the origin of the problem comes from it itself, whatever I also will post you the package.json, thank you.

Comment: Is your `package-lock.json` tracked by git ? (it should)

Comment: Yes, when we pull, package-lock.json download and we make "npm install" and "npm run build" then shows the first image

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`, your `nuxt.config.js` and `.gitignore` ? Also, why is there no `/datos/web/provider` path on the second image ? Do you build your image from the same place ?

Comment: Yes the two images have been made at the same place, now i upload nuxt.config.js and .gitignore on github

Comment: You should upload it here following the rules of SO. You should not host code elsewhere if you can host it here. That way, it will never 404 if somebody ever needs it one day.